# Question links give "Oops!" screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, error-message

Opening questions brings up the "Oops!" screen of death.
I've tried numerous ways of opening questions.

Why would that be?

Comment: I'm getting it too. It is saying that it is on their end. Give it a few hours and then check again.

Comment: Oh, good, it wasn't just me. My coworkers didn't have this issue but I did/do. Was seeing this only on Meta, now only seeing it on the main site.

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus

Comment: We know, and they are working on it.

Comment: For a time Meta was dong this too.  Meta seems to have at least recovered.

Comment: Yup - right now, any Stack Overflow link I click on in Google goes to, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/1979363/html-button-v-s-html-submit  SO is down currently.

Comment: I can confirm this. :)

Comment: Related/dupe on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277523/cant-access-questions-of-many-most-sites

Comment: :O it be broken :( please may the programming Gods fix it :)

Comment: See the [StackStatus Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) for more info.

Comment: Developer productivity across the world just went down 42%

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/714494616821702656

Comment: That's Monday for ya!

Comment: Appears to be fixed now.

Comment: Happened to me when posting an answer. Geez for a moment I thought I [broke the Internet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vywf48Dhyns).

Comment: Hey, at least someone didn't put a breaking change in *before* the Easter break :/

Answer (score 6):

According to the @StackStatus Twitter, a new build is being rolled out that corrects this issue:

https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/714495272127082496

[image]

Also this answer on Meta:

[image]

Comment: I know its not related but why that account only follows Ryan Seacrest?

Comment: WHEN IT WILL NORMALL PROGRAMMING SOON? NEED TIMEOUT

Comment: @Forcefield: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237001/why-does-stackstatus-follow-ryan-seacrest

Comment: @BoltClock just... lol